# Вычисление угла между векторами

Tags: c++

Вот написал программу, но, кажется, она вычисляет не то, что надо =)
Задание.

> Написать программу для вычисления угла фи между векторами `a=(a1,a2,a3)` и `b=(b1,b2,b3)`. Компоненты векторов вводятся пользователем. При вычислениях воспользоваться соотношением `a*b=|a|*|b|*cos(fi)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    double d;
    double a[3];
    double b[3];
    double res = 0;
    double f, h, alpha, y;
    cout << "a= ";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cout << "b= ";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        res += a[i] * b[i];
    d = res;
    // Вот здесь чувствую у меня не правильно записано 
    // (как это написать в цикле, чтобы в ручном режиме не писать)
    f = sqrt(a[1] * a[1] + a[2] * a[2] + a[3] * a[3]);
    h = sqrt(b[1] * b[1] + b[2] * b[2] + b[3] * b[3]);
    y = acos(d / (f * h));
    cout << "alpha= " << y;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте разметку кода, никто не станет это читать. Четыре пробела в начале, в справке написано. Также пользуйтесь обратными кавычками \`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексы элементов массива идут с нуля. Т.е. верно - `f=sqrt(a[0]*a[0]+a[1]*a[1]+a[2]*a[2]);`